# How do I dynamically set max_num for a django TabularInline based on a value from a foreign table?

Tags: django, django-admin

Consider the following data models:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    """A specific model of managed network switch. """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    port_count = models.IntegerField()

class Switch(models.Model):
    """A deployed instance of a managed network switch."""
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14)

class Port(models.Model):
    """A port on a deployed instance of a managed network switch."""
    switch = models.ForeignKey(Switch)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(
        protocol='IPv4', verbose_name='IP address')
    netmask = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    vlan = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='VLAN')
```

I want my Admin pages such that Ports are inlined under the Switch.  So I have:

```
class PortInLineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Port
    extra = 8
    max_num = 48

class SwitchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PortInLineAdmin]
```

This is very close to what I want to achieve.  However, what I really want
is to have the `PortInLineAdmin.max_num` be dynamically set at run-time to the
`Model.port_count` of the switch that I'm editing rather than being hard-coded
at 48 as shown above.  How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `get_max_num` in `PortInLineAdmin`:

```
class PortInLineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Port
    extra = 8

    def get_max_num(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return obj.model.port_count
```

In Django 1.5 you need a different *trick*:

```
class PortInLineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Port
    extra = 8

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.max_num = obj.model.port_count
        return super(PortInLineAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That looks great, but I couldn't get it to work and now I see why.  "New in Django 1.6".  I need a solution that will work in 1.5.

Comment: Awesome!  From reading the docs, I figured formsets would be involved but I'm new to Django and got a bit lost.  Your solution(s) worked perfectly.  I haven't tested the first (for v1.6) but it makes sense.  Both are very clear and simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
class YourModelLin(TabularLin):
model = YourModel
....

def get_max_num(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    return obj.yourmodel_set.count() + 1
```

It works perfectly in django 2.2 :)